# JavaScript error - Invalid property value

Tags: javascript, html

Using IE 6/7/8, I receive a JavaScript error code.

The line of code is:

```
document.getElementById('all').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

The IE 6/7/8 is:

```
Invalid property value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can easily help you if you can provide a code snippet.

Comment: @abales - I've updated my original post

Comment: @Rosarch, I'm actually trying to move away from being dependent on JQuery. Good idea though

Comment: Your code works for me. I don't think it's that line of code I think it's your HTML. However, it's a bad idea to use 'all' as an idea since that's a keyword in IE for accessing all elements.

Comment: Wow, you want your code to work in IE, but not be dependent on jQuery. What a masochist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this code after the DOM is completely loaded? Perhaps there is no 'panel-hlisting-all' yet? If you're using Prototype, you might try:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { // Wait until everything is loaded.
   document.getElementById('panel-hlisting-all').style.background = color;
 });
```

Just a thought — and I have no way of testing it on IE (thankfully/unfortunately), but what if you tried:

```
document.getElementById('panel-hlisting-all').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

**Added:**

Also note that `color` must be a string containing a valid CSS color (`#FFFFFF`, `rgb(255,255,255)`, `rgba(255,255,255,1)`).

Comment: I just read the JQuery comment — although not being dependant on a library has it's advantages, Event handling and Selection from API's offer predictable and often dependable results across browsers.

Comment: I changed to backgroundColor = now I receive the error: "invalid property value". Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: What is the value you have for that variable?

Comment: I'd ensure that it is a string. If you're using HEX colors, check to make sure that you didn't leave out the '#'

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to set the `backgroundColor` when you get this error, my guess would be that the property whose value is invalid - is `backgroundColor`!

Set a breakpoint on that line and find out what value `color` has.

Answer (score -1):

There no such thing as `.style.background` in JavaScript. Use `.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: I changed to backgroundColor - now I receive the error: "invalid property value". Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: What's the value of the 'color' variable?